# keepalived doesn't assign the virtual IP

Tags: haproxy, keepalived

I am testing haproxy with keepalive to 3 servers.
Haproxy server configurations work fine (USLTS4/USLTS5), but not keepalived.

The process started on both haproxy's, but the VIP is not assigned to the master (USLTS4), so not reachable from clients.

Here are haproxy and keepalived configs:

**haproxy**
[image]

**keepalived**
[image]

Both haproxy's work fine separately and loadbalance traffic

> USLTS4:~$ netstat -nlta | grep :80 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>
> USLTS5:~$ netstat -nlta | grep 80 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

No VIP assigned to the main haproxy

[image]

Tested with unicast and multicast (default) configurations.

```
unicast_peer { 
192.168.20.254
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you deliberately setting both keepalived instances to be MASTER?  Usually the passive node's state would be BACKUP.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the reply, changed state on USLTS4 form MASTER to BACKUP, made the priority higher on the master.  
Checked that apparmor disabled and iptables rules cleared. Doesn't seem to help.